# exception in initAndListen: 28595 2: No such file or directory, terminating

Tags: mongodb

after server crashed, mongod service don't start. OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 start mongo version: 3.0.0 repair option don't help, journal directory is empty after crash update mongo to 3.0.2, this is all in log file:

```
2015-04-28T14:56:45.154+0600 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is     installed, no need to zero-out data files
2015-04-28T14:56:45.154+0600 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\data\mongod.lock is not empty.
2015-04-28T14:56:45.154+0600 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2015-04-28T14:56:45.154+0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2015-04-28T14:56:45.154+0600 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:2: No such file or directory
2015-04-28T14:56:45.154+0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 2: No such file or directory, terminating
2015-04-28T14:56:45.154+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

How can I fix this?